# Generate a select menu with [(ngModel)] without using *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

Today, I spent about 3 hours trying to get a `select` menu to work without iterating over a list:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option [ngValue]="value1">First Value</option>
  <option [ngValue]="value2">Second Value</option>
</select>
```

But all of the values become undefined... Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: What *are* the values of `value1` and `value2` in the component class? Could you give a [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `NgValue` directive is looking for variables called `value1` and `value2` in your component, but they are not defined, so the value for every option is `undefined`. If you want your value to be `string`, just add `''`:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
    <option [ngValue]="'value1'">First Value</option>
    <option [ngValue]="'value2'">Second Value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: *Face palm* this is exactly what I did

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to bind the component member variables `value1` and `value2` to the option via `ngValue`. I think you forgot to define them inside your components code like:

```
public value1 = 'value1';
```

You could also go for a simple string assignment like:

```
<option ngValue="value1"></option>
```